# Calculating percents with "-" sign?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example yesterday I had 886 dollars. But today I have only 877 dollars. How can I calculate how much richer am I today than yesterday in percents ( so number of percents should be with "-" ).

How can I calculate it?

I have to do this in many ways, but unfortunately i can't get the right result.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried ${t\over y}-1$?  $t$ is today, $y$ is yesterday.

Comment: No offense ... but by your given amounts, you're becoming poorer not richer than yesterday

Comment: so number of percents should be with "-" (from my question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x_0$ be your initial amount of money, and $x_1$ be your new amount. The percent increase is calculated as follows:

$$\frac{x_1-x_0}{x_0}\cdot{100\%}$$